# How to find list of my facebook friends who are android users?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway, using either facebook grap api or any other method to find out which of my facebook friends are android users ?

I don't think there is a straight forward method to do this.
I think one way would be to mark users by reading the 'via Android/iPhone/etc/' tag in their posts.
Any ideas?

Pls Note - I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask. I would happily move this question to any stackexchange site if you suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the graph API, get the user ids for the friends, and ask for the "devices" field.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ and look for the "devices" name under Fields.